# Why this if statement creates an undefined value inside a for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, for-loop, undefined

I have created this for loop to collect all the images inside an `<ul>`. I want to collect on one hand the portrait images and on the other the ones that are in landscape, and apparently it works...

```
for ( var i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i += 1 ) {
    var images = [ imgArray ]; // Creates an array with all the images.

//Figure out which images are in landscape and in portrait.

    if ( imgArray[i].height < imgArray[i].width ) {
        var landscapeImg = [ imgArray[i] ]; // Stores landscape images.
    } else if ( imgArray[i].height > imgArray[i].width ) {
        var portraitImg = [ imgArray[i] ]; // Stores portrait images.
    };
```

... but when I log in the console `var landscapeImg` and `portraitImg` this happens.

```
[Log] [ (app.js, line 24)
<img src=​"img/​1.jpg" alt=​"Imagen 1">​
]
[Log] undefined (app.js, line 25)
[Log] [ (app.js, line 24)
<img src=​"img/​1.jpg" alt=​"Imagen 1">​
]
[Log] [ (app.js, line 25)
<img src=​"img/​2.jpg" alt=​"Imagen 2">​
]
[Log] [ (app.js, line 24)
<img src=​"img/​3.jpg" alt=​"Imagen 3">​
]
[Log] [ (app.js, line 25)
<img src=​"img/​2.jpg" alt=​"Imagen 2">​
]
[Log] [ (app.js, line 24)
<img src=​"img/​4.jpg" alt=​"Imagen 4">​
]
[Log] [ (app.js, line 25)
<img src=​"img/​2.jpg" alt=​"Imagen 2">​
]
[Log] [ (app.js, line 24)
<img src=​"img/​5.jpg" alt=​"Imagen 5">​
]
[Log] [ (app.js, line 25)
<img src=​"img/​2.jpg" alt=​"Imagen 2">​
]
```

Why I am getting an undefined value? And why the loop goes over the image 1 again?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why are you assigning var images = [ imgArray ]; every time in your for statement: You could place that before the For loop saving you some resources? Which line is line 25?

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I'll do it. Line 24 and 25 are just the console.log()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because on the first run only the code in the `if` or `else-if` will run, both sections cannot be ran one on a single iteration. This leaves one of the variables yet to be defined. For example:

```
if ( true ) {
    var landscapeImg = [ imgArray[i] ]; // Stores landscape images.
} else if ( false ) {
    var portraitImg = [ imgArray[i] ]; // Stores portrait images.
};

console.log(portraitImg) // logs undefined
console.log(landscapeImg) // logs some defined value
```

Answer (score 1):

First, a naming tip. It helps to use consistent and meaningful names. I like using plural and singular names for arrays and single items respectively: `images` is a good name for an array of images, and `image` is a good name for a single image. `landscapeImg` is *not* a good name for an array of landscape images, because it sounds like a name for a single image. `imgArray` is a fine name for an array of images, but if you have a lot of arrays it gets tedious to repeat the `Array` part over and over again. My suggestion there is to use plural names like `images` for brevity and clarity.

So I'm going to tweak the names a bit in the example below and assume the input array is called `images`. And if it's already an array, we don't need to create another array with the same thing. Also, we need to take care of square images, unless you want to lump them into either the portraits or landscapes.

One other tip: instead of repeating `imgArray[i]` several times in the code (or it would be `images[i]` in the code below), it helps to assign that to a simple variable to make the code shorter and more clear.

Finally, what you want to do is create each array *before* the loop and then push items into the appropriate array inside the loop. So it might look like this:

```
var squares = [], landscapes = [], portraits = [];

for( var i = 0;  i < images.length;  i++ ) {
    var image = images[i];
    if( image.height < image.width ) {
        landscapes.push( image );
    } else if( image.height > image.width ) {
        portraits.push( image );
    } else {
        squares.push( image );
    }
}
```